# Individual fixed effects in short experiments - a foolproof method for impact evaluation?

Tags: panel-data, experiment-design

Individual fixed effects control for all time-invariant characteristics of individuals that may affect  treatment and outcome variables. If there are no time-variant characteristics that affect the outcome, then fixed effects models are unbiased.

In a short experiment with a pre- and post-evaluation (say, up to an hour between measurements), it is easy to assume that there will be no time-variant characteristics influencing the outcome. In this case, are individual fixed effects models completely foolproof or are there other sources of bias that might creep in unnoticed?